# iPod generation 4 won't upgrade ios

Tags: ios, ipod

Please help me, my iPod 4 won't upgrade past ios 6.1.6 and this is very annoying as there are many apps that you have to have at least ios 7 or 8 for. Does anyone know how I can upgrade?! Thanks!

Comment: http://ipsw.me Shows which versions are available for each device.

Answer (score 1):

You can't update to iOS 9.  According to Apple, it's only compatible with iPod 5th & 6th generation.

Apple stops signing (authorizing) previous iOS versions shortly after the new ones come out.  Because of that, you can't update to iOS 7 or 8 because they're no longer available from Apple.

You might be able to bypass this restriction by jailbreaking your device but I don't recommend that because there's many things that can wrong, including bricking your iPod.

Comment: Maximum iOS for iPod 4 is 6.1.6 - that's just as far as it can go.